# Installing emscripten on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, emscripten

I try to install Emscripten following their instructions on the website, but I ran into some weird errors:

1. When I do ls -l in the command line in the emscripten folder, the command line returns 0, but when I look it up with finder I can find the folder 1.35.0. So I cd 1.35.0
2. There I try to run ./emcc -v, but I get this error: env: python2: No such file or directory

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your first question, but Emscripten does require a version of Python 2.x called "python2" to be available.  It doesn't matter than the Mac OS built-in version is Python 2.7.

Since the OS no longer allows sym-links to files in /usr/bin, I copied mine to /usr/local/bin and just called it python2 there.  I'm sure there is a simpler solution, but this works.